# Fluter and ios 17

Tags: swift, flutter, xcode, android-studio

Since I updated to iOS 17 when I try to test on physical devices I have to open xcode and this didn't happen before

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPad de Soporte NO CAMBIAR POR FAVOR (4) in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: MQ5RJ8B5V8
Xcode build done.                                           129.8s
You may be prompted to give access to control Xcode. Flutter uses Xcode to run your app. If access is not allowed, you can change this through your Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.